# Binary search and an error 'return' outside function

Tags: python, function, class, syntax-error

I have a little problem with my binary search function inside a class definition:

```
def searchExactIndex(self, key):
    

bottom = 0
top = self.keyc
found = False
    
    while bottom <= top and not found:
        middle = (bottom+top)/2
        
        if self.keys[middle] == key:
            found = True
        elif self.keys[middle] < key:
            bottom = middle + 1
        else:
            top = middle-1
return middle
```

Everything else here is working except When running the program I get an error:

> `while bottom <= top and not found:`
>
> IndentationError: unexpected indent

Why is this?

Comment: Are you using python? adding the language tag to the question will help it being noticed

Comment: You've probably mixed spaces with tabs as indents. Don't do that.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Indentation

Answer (score 1):

With the error you are seeing,

```
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Python is trying to tell you that something is wrong with the way you indented your code, and indeed there is, you need to look at the indentation before the first three lines in the `searchExactIndex` method.

Your code looks fine, except for the indentation, which is significant in Python. The function should look like this:

```
def searchExactIndex(self, key):
    bottom = 0
    top = self.keyc
    found = False

    while bottom <= top and not found:
        middle = (bottom+top)/2

        if self.keys[middle] == key:
            found = True
        elif self.keys[middle] < key:
            bottom = middle + 1
        else:
            top = middle-1

    return middle
```

Note the lines where `bottom`, `top`, and `found` are being set: they are indented to be inside the `searchExactIndex` method. Make sure you use one type of indentation (i.e. only spaces), and keep it consistent.

Answer (score 0):

How do you enter this code in python ?

According to your code, you should have thoses syntax errors:

If enter in a file :

```
  File "test.py", line 4
    bottom = 0
         ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

If enter in interactive python:

```
>>> def searchExactIndex(self, key):
... 
  File "<stdin>", line 2

    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

The solution is to ident **all** the content of the function :

```
def searchExactIndex(self, key):

    bottom = 0
    top = self.keyc
    found = False

    while bottom <= top and not found:
        middle = (bottom+top)/2

        if self.keys[middle] == key:
            found = True
        elif self.keys[middle] < key:
            bottom = middle + 1
        else:
            top = middle-1
    return middle
```

Also, you should take care of the case when the key is not present. For now, you always return middle.